# WSO2 IS , user account enable/disable issue

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Document ref: [wso2Is520-link-here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS520/User+Account+Locking+and+Account+Disabling#UserAccountLockingandAccountDisabling-Accountdisabling)

Followed the same in this document to setup the account enable/disable property for users.
However, using the **RemoteUserStoreManagerService** SOAP service, its not updating the claim :

> http://wso2.org/claims/identity/accountDisabled

All other claims are updatable, is it a known issue or am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the `setUserClaimValue`?

The identity claims (which has the claim URI as "http://wso2.org/claims/identity/xxxxx") can't be updated by the `setUserClaimValue` method. They can only be updated with `setUserClaimValues` method.

Comment: Great @pulasthi7 , it works thanks .. you are awesome.